# How to run script only if load balancer is NOT routing requests to it via bash script?

Tags: nginx, bash

I have 4 cloud instances. First is a load balancer (LB), and then 2 instances with the identical setup holding the application code (APP1 & APP2). And finally, I have a database instance (DB).

- DB: MySQL
- Web service: Nginx

LB will route all requests to APP1 only. If APP1 goes down, LB will route requests to APP2.

I want to write a shell script that will execute only if LB is not routing requests to it.

So, I would have a shall script called run.sh on both, APP1 and APP2. If and only if LB routes requests to APP1, would run.sh on APP2 execute via cron.

Any idea how I can figure out, from APP2, if LB is routing requests to it?

Comment: Is it possible for your run.sh script to log into the other machine and check (maybe via netstat / ps / lsof) if it is handling connections from the load-balancer?

Comment: Typically a load balancer will have an api through which you can remotely determine its current state.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
@Martin, I'd rather keep it within the machine.
@embobo, I'm actually implementing the load balancer myself, via Nginx. Keeping it super simple :)